# Maven: Running .java During Build

Tags: maven, build

I've a separate module in my project that generates classes using protobuf-maven-plugin from .proto Google ProtoBuf definition files.

I also wish to create accompanying classes, using custom java code to process the .proto files and dump the output to src/main/java/my/package/path

I'm trying to configure exec-maven-plugin calling the custom Java code but cannot get the output of this class to be included in the resulting .jar

Any insight into whether this is possible and how would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

KA.